# What decides the preposition to use in the phrase like "C'est un honneur pour notre école."?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

In the following sentence:

> C'est un honneur **pour** notre école.

It is very hard for me to know if the preposition to use is *pour* or *à*.

In these types of sentences that is in the form of *be + adjective* and *a prepositional phrase*, is the preposition to use decided by the adjective, the phrase after the preposition, or something else?

Comment: C'est lié à un usage possible de la préposition *pour*, qui sert à attribuer un sentiment, une opinion à un sujet. Voilà ce qu'en dit *Le Grand Robert* :

> En ce qui concerne une personne en tant que sujet, dans sa conscience,
> son esprit. cf. Œil (à mes yeux, à ses yeux). [...] *Il n'est plus rien pour moi, il
> était tout pour elle. | Rien ne compte plus pour nous. |*

Il faudrait en outre noter que le présentatif *c'est* est une forme particulière, différente de la forme générale *être + adjectif + préposition + complément.*

Auriez-vous des exemples, pour ce dernier point ?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the word "honneur" means "mark of esteem, of great consideration"; in the second it means "moral rectitude". There are therefore already these two clues to help you tell them apart.

When "pour" is used (un honneur pour untel, un honneur pour eux, etc.)  some honour is derived from  the situation; "pour" means here "as seen by someone, as considered from someone's point of view". In the second case (à), the person's honour (or other entity) is not "derived" as that does not apply to this concept, but the person's honour is preserved or consolidated or even enhanced; note that in the first case the indefinite article is used whereas in the other case (with "être" or without) the definite article is used; that's an other clue (and rule when translating from English to French). Moreover, one can see that the preposition is used  "logically" : someone benefits from something; in the second case, there is not really a benefit for the person involved and instead something that lies with someone (their honour) is being considered (preserved); "à" is therefore also logical enough. Here are definitions and examples from the TLFi;

> (TLFi) **Sortir, se tirer d'une situation difficile avec/à son honneur**.
>   Sortir, se tirer d'une situation difficile sans perdre la face, avec succès.
>
> - Je lui avais dit, que j'avais fait une épreuve par ma conduite avec Sara, dont elle ne s'était pas tirée à son honneur; qu'elle avait l'âme dure, et que j'étais revenu de mes sentiments pour elle.
>
> (TLFi) **Être (tout) à l'honneur de qqn**. Être à l'avantage de quelqu'un et lui valoir des marques de considération, d'estime.
>
> - Pour le développement de la saine philosophie sociale, et à l'honneur croissant des estimables esprits qui s'y livrent... .
> - Peut-être que ce sont les enfants d'un de ses hommes qui aurait été tué à côté de lui et qu'il est devenu pour ainsi dire leur tuteur. Si c'était vrai pourquoi ne pas nous le dire? Ce serait tout à son honneur. Mais je crains le pire.

The following locution has a different  meaning and should not be confused with the preceding ones.

> **Faire honneur à qqn/qqc**. Être une des causes de l'estime, de la considération qui est accordée à quelqu'un ou quelque chose; lui donner des marques de considération.

- C'est un honneur pour notre école; répétons le, le directeur de la firme a fait honneur à notre école en déclarant qu'elle y trouvait ses meilleurs ingénieurs.

In this last example we are really talking about the first concept and we do have to use "à" and not "pour", this being apparently contradictory and the reason why I mention an additional case. This can be said :  in the present case there is a verb of action and a "complément d'attribution" which is often introduced by "à".